# Many to one matching algorithm with a maximum of matches to one

Tags: python, scipy, matching

I need an algorithm that matches many (X) to one (Y).

- Given: The distances between each x and y.
- Goal: The point is to minimize the distance in the assignment.
- Constraints: Every x should be assigned to a y, not every y needs an assigned x. A maximum of 4 x
  can be assigned to one y.

Is there a procedure for this? Thank you very much for your help.

(Best if Python related answers, but no must)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I am not asking for code. You are write that I am asking for advice if somebody knows such an algorithm, I cannot find anything what is related to it. While there is a lot for bipartite matching there is nothing for this. This not bipartite matching. I cannot try anything because there is nothing to try.

Answer (score 0):

Vertically stack 4 copies of your distance matrix and solve the assignment problem on the resulting matrix.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).